# Python Key error -when trying to use statements

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code i am getting a key error on line 31, something to do with the word 'Reserved'

```
#Create a loan class that will allow members to borrow books

class Loan(Book, Member):
    """Class that allows members to reserve,cancel reservations, return and borrow books
       Librarians can extract the data
       pre-conditions: inherits from Book and member classes
       if the above is not correct the data wont be
    """
    
    
    
    @classmethod
    #set up a class in order to borrow a book
    def Borrow(cls, name, title):
        """
        

        Parameters
        ----------
        cls : TYPE
        """
        #Find ID of book/member
        BookID = Book.scan(title)[0]
        MemberID = Member.scan(name)[0]
        #check if the book is available
        Status = books[BookID]['Available']
      
        #if the book is available check then check the different reservations
        if Status == "Yes":
            #if the book is not reserves then issue the book and add a new entry
            if books[BookID]["Reserved"] == "No": #THIS IS LINE 31
                dateToday = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                loans[len(loans)+1]={'BookID':BookID, 'MemberID':MemberID, 'Date of loan': dateToday, 'Date of return':'NaN', 'Length of borrow':'NaN'}
                books[BookID]["Available"] = "No"
                print("You have now borrowed", title)
            #if the books is reserved and the member is first in the queue
            #remove the member from the reservation list and record new record
            elif books[BookID]["Reserved"] == "Yes" and books[BookID]["ReservedID"][0] == MemberID:
                dateToday = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                loans[len(loans)+1] = {'BookID':BookID, 'MemberID':MemberID, 'Date of loan': dateToday, 'Date of return':'NaN', 'Length of borrow':'NaN'}
                books[BookID]["Available"] = "No"
                Loan.RemoveReservation(name, title)
                if len(books[BookID]["ReservedID"]) == 0:
                    books[BookID]["Reserved"] = "No"
                print("You have now borrowed", title)
                #if the member has reserved the book but there is someone else renting it
            elif books[BookID]["Reserved"] == "Yes" and MemberID in books[BookID]["ReservedID"]:
               print(title, "is not available at the moment. You can reserve this though")
            #if the book isnt available and the member hasnt reserved it
            else:
                print(title, "is not available")
            #
            #
        elif Status == "No":
            if MemberID in books[BookID]["ReservedID"]:
                print(title, "not ready")
            else:
                print(title, "not ready")

Loan.Borrow(name="Charlie Roberts", title ="God Created the Integers")

print(books[Book.scan("God Created the Integer")[0]])

print(loans[len(loans)])
```

Answer (score 3):

A `KeyError` means that that key does not exist in the dictionary. If you want to check for existence of a key, either wrap it in a try/catch:

```py
try:
    doSomething(myDict['invalidKey'])
except KeyError:
    #Process error
```

OR

Check if the key exists first:

```py
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
if "a" in d.keys():
    #The key was in the dictionary
else:
    #The key wasn't in the dictionary
```

If you want to add the key to your dictionary, you'll have to set the key equal to a value first:

```py
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a']
KeyError
>>> d['a'] = "foo"
>>> d['a']
foo
```